# Could not start visual basic

Tags: vb6, ide

When  I try to start my visual basic to open a project it doesnt seem to be working and keep prompting a error 'VB6EXT.OLB' could not be register. What does that mean? Need helps on this matter, thanks

Comment: Why would a question about an IDE failing to start be off-topic?

Comment: I assume this is Visual Basic 6? On what operating system? Is it a new install?

Comment: Are you sure of the extension? Shouldn't it be VB6EXT.OLB?

Comment: This is the first time I encounter such problem and couldnt find much sources for such error, just want to knw what happen, and is there any solutions for it

Comment: theatrus: yeah is a visual basic 6, is running on windows vista, normally it would start just fine, but now im getting this error. 
John, yeah is OLB, sorry my mistake

Comment: John.P: do u knw of any solutions to it?

Comment: See @Tarpit Sahu answer for the the correct answer.

Answer (score 5):

Just Right Click on VB6.exe and CLick On Run As Administrator..
Hope It works

Comment: Ok, just able to open it with this suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

VBE6EXT.OLB is the Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility Library.  That filename seems to indicate that you're dealing with version 5.3, which apparently shipped with Microsoft Office 2000.  It would seem your VB6 project is an Office Automation project then?

Google turns up the following links, which may be helpful:

- [BUG: Interface methods in the VBA Extensibility Library (VBE) are changed](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/269116)
- [PRB: Visual Studio Setup program may include Office OLB files in setup list](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/249843)

Neither seems to directly answer your question, but they seem like a good place to start.

Since Visual Basic 6 (and Microsoft Office 2000 as well) hit end-of-life well before Windows Vista was released, there may be a fundamental conflict between them.  You might be better off trying to develop your application on an older version of Windows.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, will look into the links that you gv me, btw do think that if i downloaded the library and install it back to the visual studio would solve this error?

Comment: @kojh: Unlikely.  You'll probably need to install the entire package that included that library (which I guess would be Office 2000 in this case).

Comment: Answer written by @Tarpit Sahu  is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

**This just happened to me** (literally seconds ago) and I came HERE first stop.

I was looking for THE answer. As it happened, MS-Office 2010 offered to repair the problem...
... and, skeptically, I accepted.

To my astonishment I was soon greeted by my FAVOURITE splash screen in the world - I've got my Rubberduck

Anyway, I'm relieved **the Auto Fix worked**...